# Error in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: xml, android, manifest, android-manifest

I have a problem in the manifest when i try to use this library (com.google.android.maps)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.hellogooglemaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: An what kind of problem do you have?

Comment: import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity; won't work even if i add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in the manifest the library is not detected ! then i can't extend to  MapActivity

Comment: [2010-06-24 13:16:15 - HelloGoogleMaps] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: What is the error or exception that you get? In the xml you posted you don't have the <uses-libary>

Comment: i have no error or exeption. i'm trying to extend to MapActivity but the library is not detected. i put <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in the manifest but i still can't import com.google.android.maps

Answer (score 2):

Finally, i found the problem. i used Google APIs as Project Build Target instead of Android 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a Google API Key. Check this link: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html